# Rest API Multiple Lists in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, sharepoint

Because SharePoint works async i cannot store the data from multiple lists in array's and access them later.

I need to use 3 lists because they contain data from employees, holidays, and more.

See my code below for more information.

Is there no easier way to work with SharePoint and multiple lists to get the data. I tried also with executequeryasync but i cannot find a working solution for multiple lists. Or  to store the value of each list in an array or variable and use it in another function because it's async.

```
$(function () {
$('#title').html("Inloggen verlofaanvraag");
});


function inLoggen() {
var initialen = $('#initialen').val();
var wachtwoord = $('#wachtwoord').val();

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Lijst werknemers')/Items?$filter=wInitialen eq '" + initialen + "' and wWachtwoord eq '" + wachtwoord + "'",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var x = data.d.results;
        var werknemers = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            rInitialen = x[i].wInitialen;
            rWachtwoord = x[i].wWachtwoord;
            rVolledigenaam = x[i].wVolledigenaam;

        }

        if (i === 0) {
            alert("U hebt geen toegang tot deze pagina !");
        }
        else {
            $('#title').html("Welkom " + rVolledigenaam);
            $('#inlogform').hide();
            persoonlijketellers(werknemers);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
}


function persoonlijketellers(werknemers) {

var rId = werknemers[0].ID;

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Lijst persoonlijke tellers')/Items?$filter=pWerknemer eq '" + rId + "'",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var x = data.d.results;
        var ptellers = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        }

        wettelijkeverlofdagen(werknemers, ptellers);

    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
}

function wettelijkeverlofdagen(werknemers, ptellers) {

var rId = ptellers[0].ID;

alert(rId);

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Lijst persoonlijke tellers')/Items?$filter=pWerknemer eq '" + rId + "'",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var x = data.d.results;
        var ptellers = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        }

    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data from multiple lists in array and access them when all of your async calls are complete, you just need to use some sort of promise pattern.

jQuery's .when method is probably the most useful in a situation like this:

```
function SPData() {
    function getJsonDataAsync(url) {
        // returning the $.ajax object is what makes the next part work...
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
    }

    var requestURI1 = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/lists/..."
    var requestURI2 = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/lists/..."
    var requestURI3 = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/lists/..."            
    var req1 = getJsonDataAsync(requestURI1);
    var req2 = getJsonDataAsync(requestURI2);
    var req3 = getJsonDataAsync(requestURI3);
    // now we can do the next line, because req1/2/3 are actually deferreds
    // being returned from $.ajax
    jQuery.when(req1, req2, req3).done(function(resp1, resp2, resp3) {
        /* do something with all of the requests here...
           resp1/2/3 correspond to the responses from each call and are each an
           array that looks like: [data, statusText, jqXHR], which means that your
           data is in resp1[0], resp2[0], etc. */
    });
```

If you want, you can also just assign the returned values to variables in a higher level context, then use individual jQuery deferreds so that you can be sure all of the calls have succeeded before you start working with the data...

```
...
    var x1, x2, x3;            
    // use the .then(function() { ... }) pattern because we are just returning a
    // deferred/promise from $.ajax
    getJsonDataAsync(requestURI1).then(function(data) {
        x1 = data;
        getJsonDataAsync(requestURI2).then(function(data2) {
            x2 = data2;
            getJsonDataAsync(requestURI3).then(function(data3) {
                x3 = data3;
                // do something with x1, x2, and x3
            });
        });
    });    
}
```